# The row number 0 is out of bounds - ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have been racking my brain on this.  I am getting this error message "The row number 0 is out of bounds."

```
<cfparam name="Form.#PartNumberVar#" default="">
 ---- Error on the line below ----
<td><cfinput type="text" value="#Form[PartNumberVar]#" class="prodQuantity" name="#PartNumber#" validate="integer" message="Please enter whole numbers into the Quantity Field."></td>
```

I am stumped.

From what I saw in the Error StackTrace: Detail [empty string], ErrNumber   0

StackTrace:
coldfusion.runtime.QueryFunction$RowNumberOutOfBoundException: The row number 0 is out of bounds. at coldfusion.runtime.QueryFunction.QuerySetCell(QueryFunction.java:499) at coldfusion.runtime.QueryFunction.QuerySetCell(QueryFunction.java:332) at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.QuerySetCell(CFPage.java:1258) at cfNewTreadsDisplay2ecfm1920230382.runPage(E:\WebSites\MOTest\MO\ordering\Includes\NewTestDisplay.cfm:133) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2986) at cfTestingDST2ecfm847829206.runPage(E:\WebSites\MOTest\MO\ordering\Includes\TestingDST.cfm:131) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2986) at cfTesting2ecfm1463952034.runPage(E:\WebSites\MOTest\MO\ordering\Testing.cfm:368) at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734) at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570) at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45) at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:141) at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:78) at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:151) at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:198) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: A *ColdFusion* error? Nothing in that code there would cause an error "The row number 0 is out of bounds.". Can you post the *actual* error - copy and pasted from the screen. This will include line refs, and indeed highlight the code that is problematic.  Can you also detail what troubleshooting steps you've done? What do all the relevant variables contain? It'll be a matter of something not having the value you think it does.

Comment: It *sounds* like `partnumbervar` is set to 0, causing `#form[partnumbervar]#` to try to access index/row 0 of the form object.

Comment: I never name my structure keys as pure numbers, but `<cfset form[0]="test"><Cfoutput>#form.0# - #form[0]# - #form["0"]#</cfoutput>` works in cf9 and and railo 4. (Even knowing this, I still wouldn't name variables as pure numbers.). Googling leads me to believe this is an SQL error.

Comment: From what I saw in the Error StackTrace: Detail [empty string], ErrNumber 0

Comment: Can you paste the *complete* error message, including the stack trace?

Comment: Like Adam said, that error has nothing to do with the code you posted. Look at the second line of the trace, the cause is a call to `QuerySetCell`. Based on the error message, it sounds like you are calling the function with an bad row number: `0`. Row numbers start at one. You need to find that code an fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are trying to set a value to row number 0, but query's row number is started from 1.
If you done it so, you may get this error.

Please try this code if you can't understand me.

> ```
>   <cfset test = queryNew("Name,WorkPlace")>
>   <!--- You should use queryAddRow() for using r0w number 1 --->
>   <cfset queryAddRow(test)>
>   <!--- Please test this with 1's instead of 0's --->
>   <cfset querySetCell(test, "Name", 'XXXXX', 0)>
>   <cfset querySetCell(test, "WorkPlace", 'YYYYYY', 0)>
>   <cfdump var="#test#" />
> ```

Comment: (Edit) @mrmcg - As you can see, the example above reproduces the error you are getting by deliberately using an invalid row number ie "0". Valid row numbers must be > 0 and <= theQuery.recordCount

Comment: This is how we are setting things up.

<cfif FirstQry.Desc is not "">
<cfquery datasource="dbTesting" name="qryTest">
 Select * From Test Where ID = '#FirstQry.ID#'
</cfquery>
  
<cfoutput>
  <!--- Things here... --->
</cfoutput>
</cfif>

Comment: Is that new code? Because it does not seem to have anything to do with the original error message. Side note, you should be using `cfqueryparam` on the ID value and any other query parameters.